# How do you handle attaching JavaScript to UserControls in ASP.NET and keep multiple instance isolated?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Lets say you need to attach some JavaScript functionality to an ASP.NET User Control of which there might be multiple instances on any given page.  Because JavaScript has shared global state, what techniques can you use to keep the client state and behavior for each instance of a control separate?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need refactoring? Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the main thing you can do is make sure your JavaScript functions are abstract enough that they are not coupled to specific instances of HTML controls - have them accept parameters that allow you to pass various instances of objects in.

The JavaScript that does whatever magic you need to be done should only exist once in your page regardless of how many instances of a user control you have on a given page, thus your functions need to be ignorant of that fact.

Without more information about what you are trying to do, there is little more I can offer in the way of help; it would depend on your circumstance.

---

EDIT: One way I have dealt with particular aspects of this problem is to create a static property on the user control (thus it is the same variable across multiple instances) that tracks the client-side IDs of the various user control elements (the user control adds the client IDs to this list in the ***control's*** OnLoad event); then, in the ***page's*** OnPreRender event (IIRC), render those out in a JavaScript variable that my code knows to look for on the client and operate on. I don't know if that makes sense, but it might help someone...

Answer (score 0):

```
function <%=this.ClientID %>_myButton_onclick()
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

and

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="<%=this.ClientID %>_myButton_onclick()">
```

Notice in this case the control is a regular HTML control.

Comment: The main problem with this code is that now we have a bunch of wrapper functions polluting the global namespace - there are other issues as well, such as the fact that this is too much like horrid, classic-ASP-like inline code... :) But that is just a matter of preference, it isn't too evil...

Comment: It may be ugly, but it answers the question...

I prefer going with the 'make the javascript functions generic and pass in everything' approach, but for simple controls, this would work.

Comment: @Jason, initially I approached this in the same manner in your answer.  But like you, I encountered the problem of 'how do get associated controls.  I thought about storing associated id's like you did, but felt the above approach is self contained, and obvious to maint. Developers.

Comment: @Jason, The above code also makes it very easy to add and control js event handers, so instead of DoSomething(), you would have <%=this.Attributes["ControlClickEvent"]%>.  I would expect the bulk of the code would be in an external js file ... this is simply an easy to maintain segway into it.

Comment: I understand the trade offs and they are worth considering - however, the resulting pollution to the global namespace is, for me, worth avoiding. Not only that, but I really don't think the method I suggest is really harder to maintain. To each his own!

Comment: @Jason, I actually agree with you more than you may think.  Mostly, it's just a different tack.

Answer (score 0):

If your control has more than one function, you can put it in an external js files and refer to it.

```
 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("searchcontrol.js","includes/searchcontrol.js");
```